# Prevent system font from overriding app font family

Tags: android, fonts

In my styles.xml I've done this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

I want to keep my app with the font family I've set up there.

However, if I go to my phone settings and change the font to, for example, "Choco cooky", my entire app will use "Choco cooky" as font family instead of the one I set up in styles.xml.

I've already tried to set fontFamily for each TextView, but didn't work.

How do I force my app to use the font I want instead of system font setup by the user?